# React native - Data fetch from Async storage before rendering the app component

Tags: javascript, react-native, localization

I am creating an iOS app on React Native and want to support multi languages for the app. 
The application works when set the target language, but when I open the app again it shows the default language. I am trying to get the defined language from async storage but it does not reflect the changes and render the app component. I ma using context api for localization.

I use the Launchscreen.xib for showing the splash screen and hide this splash screen using react-native-splash-screen method SplashScreen.hide() in app.js useEffect hook and I want to set the previously chosen language before loading the app component.

Localization.js file -

```
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react';
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import en from './translations/en.json';
import de from './translations/de.json';
import bg from './translations/bg.json';
import it from './translations/it.json';
import nl from './translations/nl.json';
import pl from './translations/pl.json';
import pt from './translations/pt.json';
import ru from './translations/ru.json';
import fr from './translations/fr.json';
import es from './translations/es.json';



const APP_LANGUAGE = 'appLanguage';
const DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = 'en';



const languages = {en, de, bg, it, nl, pl, pt, ru, fr, es};

const translations = new LocalizedStrings(languages);

export const LocalizationContext = createContext({
    translations,
    setAppLanguage: () => {},
    appLanguage: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    initializeAppLanguage: () => {},
  });



export const LocalizationProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [appLanguage, setAppLanguage] = useState(DEFAULT_LANGUAGE);
   //console.log(appLanguage);
    const setLanguage = language => {
      translations.setLanguage(language);
      setAppLanguage(language);
      AsyncStorage.setItem(APP_LANGUAGE, language);
    };

    const initializeAppLanguage = async () => {
      const currentLanguage = await AsyncStorage.getItem(APP_LANGUAGE);
      console.log('language' , currentLanguage);
      if (currentLanguage === null) {
        let localeCode = DEFAULT_LANGUAGE;
        const supportedLocaleCodes = translations.getAvailableLanguages();
        const phoneLocaleCodes = RNLocalize.getLocales().map(
          locale => locale.languageCode,
        );
        phoneLocaleCodes.some(code => {
          if (supportedLocaleCodes.includes(code)) {
            localeCode = code;
            return true;
          }
        });
        setLanguage(localeCode);
      } else {
        setLanguage(currentLanguage);
      }
      onSuccess();
    };

    return (
      <LocalizationContext.Provider
        value={{
          translations,
          setAppLanguage: setLanguage,
          appLanguage,
          initializeAppLanguage,
        }}>
        {children}
      </LocalizationContext.Provider>
    );
  };
```

App.js file

```
import React, {useEffect, useContext, useState} from 'react';
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import loginReducer from '_store/reducers/login.js';
import transportReducer from '_store/reducers/transport.js';
import gpsReducer from '_store/reducers/gpslogger.js';

import AppNavigator from '_navigations/AppNavigator';

import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import FlashMessage from 'react-native-flash-message';
import {LocalizationContext} from './Localization';


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: loginReducer,
  transport: transportReducer,
  gps:  gpsReducer
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(logger, ReduxThunk)));

const App = props => {
  const {initializeAppLanguage, appLanguage} = useContext(LocalizationContext);
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeAppLanguage();
    SplashScreen.hide();


  }, []);

  return (
   <Provider store={store}>

      <AppNavigator />

      <FlashMessage />
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I achieve the required behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a separate splash screen and putting a setTimeout method there. it gives time to fetch the data from async storage and then navigate to main app.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing sth that achieve the same wanted behavior in `app.js`

```
setI18nConfig = () => {
    const {dispatch} = this.store;
    const translationGetters = {
      ar: () => require("../src/assets/translations/ar.json"),
      en: () => require("../src/assets/translations/en.json"),
    };

    const translate = helpers.translate();

    const fallback = { languageTag: "en", isRTL: false };

    const { languageTag, isRTL } = this.appLanguage ?  this.appLanguage  : (RNLocalize.findBestAvailableLanguage(Object.keys(translationGetters)) || fallback)

    dispatch(setAppLanguage({
      languageTag,
      isRTL
    }));

    if(!this.appLanguage) {
      this.appLanguage = {languageTag, isRTL}
    }

    // clear translation cache
    translate.cache.clear();

    // set i18n-js config
    i18n.translations = { [languageTag]: translationGetters[languageTag]() };
    i18n.locale = languageTag;
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rowan, Thanks for the quick response. I have few questions. 1. where did this helpers come from? 2. Are you calling this function in useEffect() hook of app.js 3. In order to translate all the pages , are you using context api or just this enough? Thanks!!